# Clarification of LLNs when non i.i.d. observations

Tags: convergence, law-of-large-numbers, heterogeneity

I have a question on how to interpret Law of Large Numbers. Its meaning seems to me clear when we are in the i.i.d. case:

*Consider $(Y_i)_{i=1}^n$ i.i.d. random variables with $\mu\equiv E(Y_1)<\infty$. Then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \rightarrow_p \mu$*

I am confused about what represents $\mu$ in the non i.i.d. case: any set of sufficient conditions weaker than i.i.d. should anyhow imposes at least that $E(Y_1)=...=E(Y_n)\equiv \mu$?

Comment: Yes, usually the random variables would be assumed to have the same mean, and often the same distribution.  "Non" i.i.d. typically means a relaxation of the independence assumption.

Comment: You can always define $Z_i:=Y_i-E[Y_i]$, which would reduce the problem to random variables with mean 0. Note that this approach would require $\lim_n\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE[Y_i]$ to be finite.

Comment: But a sequence is also not i.i.d. if the variables are not identically distributed or neither independent or identically distributed.You should be precise about what the condition actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the comments are of course right that iid-ness is the leading case, and that dependence is the leading departure from iid-ness, it is not necessary for a LLN that the means are identical.

Here is a version of a LLN taken from [White, Asymptotic Theory for Econometricians](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0127466525), Theorem 3.7, who references [Chung (1974, pp. 125-126)](https://books.google.de/books/about/A_course_in_probability_theory.html?id=zu80w7wd40UC) (link is to a newer edition, where page numbers will likely differ) for a proof.

> Let $\{\mathcal{Z}_t\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables,
>   with finite means $\mu_t\equiv E(\mathcal{Z}_t)$. If for some
>   $\delta>0$,
>   $\sum_{t=1}^\infty(E|\mathcal{Z}_t-\mu_t|^{1+\delta})/t^{1+\delta}<\infty$, then $\bar{\mathcal{Z}}_n-\bar{\mu}_n\stackrel{a.s.}{\to}0$.

That is, heterogenous means are allowed for the sample average to converge almost surely to the average of the means, provided they are not "too" heterogenous.